# Trello API learning through Postman

Tags: trello

Am learning the Trello API documentation through Postman. I have been following the documentation here https://developers.trello.com/get-started/intro. And have authorized **Server Token** on the test account.

Note: Keys where provided through https://trello.com/app-key

However was trying to do this request, it always returns this response.

Response

- HTTP Status : 401
- Body/Content : invalid key
- Custom headers (x-trello-version) : 1.855.2

Request

- HTTP Method : GET
- URL : https://api.trello.com/1/members/[username]?key=[application_key]&token=[optional_auth_token]
- URL params [username]  : me / user_with_server_token_authorised
- URL params [application_key] : server token access key
- URL params [optional_auth_token] : OAuth 1 secret

---

Am I doing it wrong?

x-post : [reddit.com/r/trello](https://www.reddit.com/r/trello/comments/5tkdao/testing_trello_api_through_postman/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have the keys mixed up.

> URL params [application_key] : server token access key
>   URL params [optional_auth_token] : OAuth 1 secret

You should use the `app key` for `application_key` and `token` for `optional_auth_token` from [trello.com/app-key](https://trello.com/app-key)

**edit:** If this doesn't work - share your entire path you're using (block the token)

Comment: Applied `app key` (Developer API Keys) and `token` from OAuth as displayed on https://trello.com/app-key. Still returning 401 / invalid token with https://api.trello.com/1/members/me or https://api.trello.com/1/members/<username>.

Comment: I think your `app key` is right but `token` is wrong. Check trello.com/app-key again. `app secret` is under the header **Oath**. You need to click the link *token* in the 2nd paragraph and then follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks for this information I just have to generate new token from the Developer API key (through **Server Token** application).